# ¿Como Soluciono No database provider has been configured for this DbContext?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Cree un `CRUD` con una `Api`, y todo funciona bien, puedo manipular los datos de manera exitosa desde mi `controller`, cree una `class` llamada `LogsE`, para poder guardar allí las excepciones pero al momento de guardarlas, me arroja el siguiente error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

No se porque cuando utilizo esa `class` no me reconoce mi proveedor de BD. pero en el controlador funciona perfectamente.

**Anexo Código `Controller`**

```
public class LibraryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApiDbContext context;
        public LibraryController(ApiDbContext context) => this.context = context;

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult BookShefLinePut(BookShefLine bookShefLine, int id)
        {
            var MSJ = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                BookShefLine bksl = context.bookshelfline.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == id);
                if (bksl == null)
                {
                    MSJ = "ID DOESN'T EXIST";
                    return new JsonResult(MSJ);
                }
                bksl.shelfid = bookShefLine.shelfid;
                context.SaveChanges();
                MSJ = "ROWS AFFECTED";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MSJ = ex.Message + " --- " + ex.InnerException + " --- " + ex.StackTrace;

                LogsE error = new LogsE(); //AQUI HAGO MI INTANCIA PARA MI CLASE 
                error.SaveError(MSJ); // Y GUARDAR AL MOMENTO DE UNA EXCEPCION

                MSJ = "Ocurrio un Error Interno";
            }
            return new JsonResult(MSJ);
        }
}
```

**Anexo Código de mi DBContext**

```
public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApiDbContext()
        {
        }
        public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {      
        }
        public DbSet<BookShefLine> bookshelfline { get; set; }
           
        public DbSet<LogsError> logserror { get; set; }
    }
```

**Anexo Código de mi class para guardar la excepciones**

```
public class LogsE : DbContext
    {
        private readonly ApiDbContext context;
        public LogsE(ApiDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public LogsE()
        {
            context = new ApiDbContext();
        }
        public void SaveError(string MSJ)
        {
          var ErrorL = new LogsError();
          ErrorL.messag = MSJ;
          ErrorL.datetime = DateTime.Now;
          context.logserror.Add(ErrorL); //EXPLOTA EN ESTA LINEA
          context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Anexo mi modelo de LogsE**

```
public class LogsError
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string messag { get; set; }
        public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
    }
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal o que me pueda estar faltando, agradezco sus sugerencia para solventar mi problema

**EDITAR**

Agregando el siguiente codigo en mi ApiDbContext logro solventar pero no es buena idea dejar en esa clase mis datos de conexion a mi BD, para eso esta el archivo appsetting.config

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
  optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=127.0.0.1; Port=5455; Database=TEST; UserId=USER; Password=12345; Timeout=15; ");
  base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Comment: ah ok, estas usando IOC y le estas inyectando el contexto.. entonces ok..

Comment: puede que porque tu log no hereda de controllerbase, entonces no este funcionando IOC? por el error, no le estaria llegando el context. Igual veo que al constructor por defecto el contexto lo creas... raro... ahhh ya lo vi... Cuando creas el log, estas pasando al constructor del contexto vacio, no al otro constructor que sabe cual es el contexto.. por eso esta vacio tu contexto...

Comment: aunque lo heredase de controllerbase, igual no funcionaria, porque hice la prueba, no se si llamarlo vacío, ya que el simplemente no reconoce mi proveedor de BD, antes si llegaba vacío y me decía referencia como instancia no inicializado, entonces cree en el contructor inicializo mi instancia que es context = new ApiDbContext();. Pero aun asi estoy estancado en el error

Comment: es que context = new ApiDbContext();. llama al constructor vacio, que no tiene contexto.. fijate que en ApiDbContext tenes dos constuctores, uno que sabe caul es la base porque hereda de base y tiene un parametro, y el otro vacio, que no sabe nada... estas usando el vacio... yo no se como se soluciona, pero busca por ahi.... me parece que tu log, deberia ser IOC como el resto, asi recibe tu contexto....

Comment: Claro, por eso pierde mi context y no reconoce ningún proveedor de BD, que problemita vale. Gracias @gbianchi, Seguire indagando

Comment: Pero fijate que usas IOC.. tambien usa IOC para el logger... de esa forma, a todas las clases asi como les pasas el contexto, les pasas el logger y listo....

Comment: Estoy un poco confundido con IOC, al parecer estoy utilizando algo que no se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo lo siguiente haz tu propio DbContext en este caso LoggerDbContext el cual herede de DbContext, usas el Constructor que recibe como parámetro el DbContextOptions,para obtener el string de conexión desde el appsettings o de algún archivo de configuración externo, haciendo eso tienes que configurar este nuevo DbContext (LoggerDbContext) en tu Startup, al tener esto, creas una interfaz, este caso IMyLogger, con el método SaveError(), implementas esta interfaz como consideres mejor. Ahora bien aquí esta la importancia de usar la inyección de dependencias y no hacer news(). En el constructor de la clase que implemente IMyLogger, inyectas el LoggerDbContext,y ahora solo queda configurar este nuevo servicio (IMyLogger) en tu startup, de esta manera donde necesites usar tu logger solo inyectas IMyLogger y listo, el código te quedaría algo así:

```
    public class MyLogger : IMyLogger 
    {
        private readonly LoggerDbContext _appDbContext;

        public MyLogger(LoggerDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
        }
        public void SaveError(Exception error)
        {
            _appDbContext.MyError.Add(new MyError
            {
                Code = error.GetHashCode().ToString(),
                Message = error.Message,
            });
            _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public interface IMyLogger
    {
        void SaveError(Exception error);
    }

    public class LoggerDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Configuracion> Configuraciones { get; set; }

        public LoggerDbContext(DbContextOptions<LoggerDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
     }
```

Recuerda agregar tus servicios al startup:

```
 services.AddDbContext<LoggerDbContext>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UseSqlServer(_conf.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

services.AddTransient<IMyLogger, MyLogger>();
```

Lo puedes usar en tus controladores de la siguiente manera:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMyLogger _myLogger;

        public TestController(IMyLogger myLogger)
        {
            _myLogger = myLogger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetError()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("My error");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _myLogger.SaveError(e);
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

**Mi recomendación final es que uses una librera para logear tus errores ya sea en tu base de datos o en un archivo, por ejemplo puedes usar Serilog.**

Comment: Tendria entonces 2 DbContext, una para mi controlador que es ApiDbContext y este nuevo que me indicas para las clases LoggerDbContext ?

Comment: Correcto eso seria lo recomendado.

Comment: Perfecto, hay algo que no me queda claro, en el controlador cada vez que hay una excepcion el entra en el catch, y  yo hacia mi instancia hacia esa clase, sigo instanciando es decir seria MyLogger my = new MyLogger(); y utulizo con my el SaveError?

Comment: Te voy a colocar un ejemplo en la respuesta.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Posgressql mi startup quedo  asi services.AddDbContext<LoggerDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("conecString")));

Comment: Listo, Muchas gracias uni tambien mi apidbcontext en el ctor del controlador de esa manera tengo los 2 y del lado de MyLogger ajuste también la manera de insertar los datos. Agradecido, debo aprender a usar interface veo que es muy útil